# Javascript, console.log prints prints object, but property is undefined

Tags: javascript, console, undefined, execution

And I have a function that reads in level data. This is the snippet in question; actors is an array and I'm looping over it until i find an actor of type player.

```
function Level(plan) {
   //Cut snippet..........
    this.player = this.actors.filter(function(actor) {
        return actor.type == "player";
    });

    console.log(this.player);
//................  
}
```

The player object,

```
function Player(pos) {
    this.pos = pos
    this.size = new Vector(0.8, 1.5);
    this.speed = new Vector(0, 0);
}
Player.prototype = new Actor();
Player.prototype.type = "player"
```

The issue is that in the console, the

```
console.log(this.player)
```

will show all the correct details, but when i try to log the position for example

```
console.log(this.player.pos)
```

I get undefined. Its a simple program, I'm not using ajax or anything. Thought it might be do with execution order, can someone explain this to me and a solution? If it is todo with execution order, an explanation would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much,
Rainy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get `undefined` because when you filter your `actor` array, you get a new array as a result. So `console.log(this.player)` outputs an array, not a single object.

You need to get the first element of the array `this.player` to output its `pos` property.

Something like this:

```
if(this.player.length > 0) 
    console.log(this.player[0].pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` instead of `filter` for a single player.

```
  this.player = this.actors.reduce(function(current, actor) {
      return actor.type === 'player' ? actor : current;
  });
```